# Get text of a tag in different format in cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm using cheerio npm package to extract the datas from the websites for my node app

Below is the snippet of the code from my app:

```js
const response = await axios.get(
  "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com/search/?q=" +
  param
);
console.log("Response got");
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

const chunk1 = $("h1.text-primary a ").text();
console.log(chunk1);
```

With the above code I'm targetting the text from the following tag:

```html
<h1 class="text-primary font-weight-bold media-heading h4" itemprop="title">
  <a href="/teacher-107/" class="no-uline" title="Teacher">
Teacher
</a>
  <meta itemprop="employmentType" content="Full Time">
</h1>
```

The issue I'm having is there are 4 tag block like this, cheerio does gets the text of the tag but gives text from all 4 tag as a single string like: `Teacher Plumber Police Army` but would like to have it in array, object or separate string.

How do I do that ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out myself

```js
 let jobTitles=[];
$('h1.text-primary ').find('a').each(function(index, element) {
  jobTitles.push($(element).text());
  index
});
```